# open-uri works but net::http, why?

Tags: ruby

I'm making a HTTPS call, debugging as the following. open_uri works fine:

```
irb(main):053:0* r=OpenURI::open_uri("https://192.168.8.123/api/1.0/appliance-management/components/component/status", opts)
=> #<StringIO:0x007fc6e4a8ee38 @base_uri=#<URI::HTTPS https://192.168.8.123/api/1.0/appliance-management/components/component/status>, @meta={"cache-control"=>"private", "expires"=>"Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT", "set-cookie"=>"JSESSIONID=B117FD42DA5509EBF99627C08332F249; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly", "content-type"=>"application/json", "transfer-encoding"=>"chunked", "date"=>"Fri, 15 Apr 2016 14:16:08 GMT", "server"=>""}, @metas={"cache-control"=>["private"], "expires"=>["Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT"], "set-cookie"=>["JSESSIONID=B117FD42DA5509EBF99627C08332F249; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly"], "content-type"=>["application/json"], "transfer-encoding"=>["chunked"], "date"=>["Fri, 15 Apr 2016 14:16:08 GMT"], "server"=>[""]}, @status=["200", "OK"]>
```

But Net::HTTP always gets ReadTimeout error:

```
irb(main):096:0* http = Net::HTTP.new('192.168.8.123', 443)
=> #<Net::HTTP 192.168.8.123:443 open=false>
irb(main):097:0> http.use_ssl = true
=> true
irb(main):099:0> http.verify_mode=OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
=> 0
irb(main):102:0* req = Net::HTTP::Get.new("/api/1.0/appliance-management/components/component/status", {})
=> #<Net::HTTP::Get GET>
irb(main):104:0* req.basic_auth('admin', 'default')
=> ["Basic YWRtaW46ZGVmYXVsdA=="]
irb(main):106:0* http.request(req)
Net::ReadTimeout: Net::ReadTimeout
        from /opt/ruby/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/protocol.rb:158:in `rescue in rbuf_fill'
```

What's wrong with my Net::HTTP code?

Comment: can you confirm 192.168.8.123 is reachable on port  443?
`telnet 192.168.8.123 443`
should respond with 
`Connected to 192.168.8.123.
Escape character is '^]'.`

if so

Comment: As you can see, open_uri works.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured the problem. That's because of a change in Ruby 2.2. In Ruby 1.9.1, Net::HTTP by default doesn't use proxy, but in Ruby 2.2, Net::HTTP by default get proxy from ENV. Thus, in Ruby 2.2, when we initialize a Net::HTTP object, we have to explicitly force to not use proxy:

```
http = Net::HTTP.new(ip, port, nil)
```